# What's the best way to highlight errors in an unconventional form?

Tags: usability, forms, interaction-design, errors, jobs

Over at UXswitch we created a WYSIWYG form for posting a new UX job. Have a look http://www.uxswitch.com/post-job. Our job adverts are like an infographic and they are built on the fly.

Problem is, if an error occurs, you kinda have to go looking for it. Because the form is not very linear, most people miss out on at least something, preventing them from posting the job successfully. Huge bummer!

Any ideas on how we could make the errors more obvious would be much appreciated :) See example below.

[image]

Comment: It has to be asked: Why is a site that's supposedly designed for UXers using such an atypical form?

Comment: Why the form is not linear? It should be broken down into few clear steps and be mobile friendly.

Comment: @DA01 Looking back on it, it might have been better to have a straight forward form that ended up in creating the nice infographic.

Comment: @Ades the current form is mobile friendly but, again might have been better it it was straightforward. We live and learn :)

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at the page, it would seem that one way of handling this is to issue a page wide banner/overlay which identifies errors and on-click the user is directed to the element which is wrong/missing. The element can also be highlighted.

Comment: nice one, great suggestion,

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean with the not-so-obviousness of the error.

To look at it another way: could you indicate progress in a non-linear way (related to the form information, but not step by step), which gives a completely blatant indication of what's DONE and what's PENDING? Pending can do along with glowing perhaps to hit it home (a subtle glowing or animation can grab attention in a deliberate way). Then, if you hit the area that's pending, you get sent to the dialog for the area of the form that's missing...OR whatever is pending could have the same quality of pending for the progress indication.

I've found in the past, conversational error messages or CTAs (which are essential to go forward) can be difficult because being direct is more difficult within the tone constraints of a friendly pal. But at the same time, Slack and others seem to do it well, so it's doable. Just an added challenge to this mix.

Comment: I definitely think you have a point with the overly friendly tone, it does not say' you must do this to proceed' ... point taken.